# php iteration ul segmentation

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, html-lists

Currently, I fetch data from MySQL as follows:

```
$catmapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_BusinessCategoryMapper();
$result = $catmapper->getBusinessCategory();
```

I iterate the result from above using `for` loop into `<li>` tag as follows:

```
$mcat = "<ul>";
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
    $mcat = $mcat . "<li class='refinecategory'><a id='refine_category_0_0' class='browse-category' href='/business/searchreviews?mct=active' rel='active'>".$result[$i]['cat_name']."</a></li>";
}
$mcat = $mcat . "</ul>";
```

But this will generate a huge list within the `ul` tag. How can I break the above statement into multiple `ul` tags? Within each `ul` I need only 5 `li` tags, if more than that another `ul` will generate and add the next `li` into it.

Comment: if (($i % 5) == 0) { add a ul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would "listen" for when `$i` is evenly divisible by 5 like so:

```
$mcat = "<ul>";
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
    if ($i % 5 == 0 && $i > 0) {
        $mcat .= "</ul><ul>";
    }
    $mcat .= "<li class='refinecategory'><a id='refine_category_0_0' class='browse-category' href='/business/searchreviews?mct=active' rel='active'>".$result[$i]['cat_name']."</a></li>";
}
if ($i % 5 != 0) {
    $mcat .= "</ul>";
}
```

That should cause your list to be split every 5 items. I haven't tested it so if you happen to get an extra list created when you have an exactly divisible by 5 number of items, you should do `if (($i-1) % 5 != 0) {` for the last `if` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the MOD operator to to something special every 5 iterations of your loop.

```
$mcat = "<ul>";
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
$mcat = $mcat . "<li class='refinecategory'><a id='refine_category_0_0' class='browse-category' href='/business/searchreviews?mct=active' rel='active'>".$result[$i]['cat_name']."</a></li>";
if($i % 5){
$mcat = $mcat . "</ul><ul>";
}
}
$mcat = $mcat . "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code with mod

```
$mcat = "<ul>";
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++){
    if($i%5 == 0  && $i > 0) {
        $mcat .= "</ul><ul>";
    } else {
        $mcat = $mcat . "<li class='refinecategory'><a id='refine_category_0_0' class='browse-category' href='/business/searchreviews?mct=active' rel='active'>".$result[$i]['cat_name']."</a></li>";
    }
}
$mcat = $mcat . "</ul>";
```

Comment: Wouldn't the else cause every 5th row to be skipped?

Comment: why there is empty <ul></ul>

Comment: It doesn't check at the beginning to see if $i is greater than 0 since 0 % 5 = 0. Adding that to the if statement should fix it.